# Hadoop command does not execute from java prcoessbuilder

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I have this script.

```
log_file_name=dataProcessor
export pwd=`pwd`
echo "in data processing"
log_file_path=LOGS/data-processor/
logfile=$log_file_path$log_file_name.log
log_file_home_path=LOGS
export LOG_FILE_HOME_PATH=$log_file_home_path
export DATA_EXTRACTION_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION=$pwd/config.properties
export LIBJARS=/home/data-extraction/2.12.2.1/data-extraction/lib/*.jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/abc/lib/*.jar
echo `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`
hadoop jar data-processor-*.jar com.impl.JobSubmission -libjars ${LIBJARS} &> $log_file_home_path/process.log
echo "in data processing done"
```

When I execute it from putty, it works properly, but it fails when we execute it using java ProcessBuilder. It fails with "Hadoop command not found" error.
Below is the Java code, which I am using to execute script.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command.trim());
//builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
exitStatus = process.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  output.append(line + "\n");
  System.out.print(line);
}
```

Comment: post more details on how are you running in java `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: removed excess whitespace in code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the other script.
Script one(1) starts Java application, which internally calls second script(s2), which was falling. Script one(S1), was setting invalid PATH, instead of PATH, path was used, which was creating whole problem.